# How to make sbt reload EVERYTHING?

Tags: sbt

I have this little alias in my `$HOME/.sbtrc` which generally works quite well at making sbt reload everything, re-resolve everything, re-prepare everything for Eclipse, etc.:

```
alias full-reload=;reload;clean;update;eclipse with-source=true
```

However, I couldn't use this when I upgraded the sbteclipse sbt plugin today - sbt stubbornly refused to even start, because it didn't recognise the existence of a settings key that I was trying to set in my project's `build.sbt` that exists only in the newer version of the sbteclipse plugin, and the only way I could find to work around the issue was to delete the old version of the plugin from the ivy cache and restart sbt. How can I do a *full* full reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my alias to reload plugins as well, which would have been needed for this problem:

```
alias full-reload=;reload plugins;clean;reload return;clean;update;eclipse with-source=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the entire `$HOME/.ivy2/cache` directory and restarting sbt, then using the above alias (in every affected project), should work - but that's a bit of a sledgehammer approach!